# What is the etymology of おっこっている?

Tags: grammar

In this passage :

> 「あらお父さん、三人この中へおっこっているわ。もう死んだかもしれないわ」

おっこっている means "to fall" but as far as I know "to fall" in Japanese is the verb 落ちる (which I see a lot throughout the same book).
What is the original form of おっこっている here, searching in the dictionary I get no results.

Answer (score 0):

「おっこちる」is「落ちる」-> [link](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8B/) + 「～ている」

Comment: The regular teiru-form of 落っこちる is 落っこ**ち**ている, so there is a sound change (音便) here.

Comment: @hiroki  `「おっこちる」is「落ちる」` -- How does おっこちる differ from 落ちる? Are they interchangeable always? `「～ている」` -- Why is it おっこ**っ**ている, not おっこちている?

Comment: 「おっこちる」is broken exporession of 「おちる」as informal expression. Some people use in casual conversation.  「あらお父さん、三人この中へおっこっているわ。」is family's dialogue to their father.

Comment: I think 「おっこっている」is shorten expression of 「おっこちている」. 「おっこちている」is a little to say! :-)

Comment: I'm quite curious what the derivation is, but I cannot find any solid information. Any ideas what the おっこ- on the front comes from?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi  https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12209153262?query=落っこちる%20語源

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, thank you for the link. I find Tai's analysis somewhat lacking; this seems less like just //k// insertion, and more like two different things happening. All the adjectival examples appear to be suffixation with 濃い, which makes sense as an intensifier. For verbs, if this were //ko// insertion to emphasize, we'd expect to see this in other verbs. However, the only verbs I'm aware of that have this are the おっこちる・おっことす pair. Japanese doesn't really do infixes, and after chewing on this for a while, I find myself thinking this must be a prefixing element.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Could verbs like 引っこ抜く、ぶっこ抜く be related?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, oo, thank you, I wasn't familiar with either of those. That certainly looks like an infix, as the only compounding verb element I can think of that might work phonologically is こむ -- but that fails semantically on 引っこ抜く. Notably these are all //ko//, not just the //k// that Tai mentions. Hmm, hmm. If you come up with any more examples, I'd love to hear about them.